# set Select Cell Editor value in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid in Angular, I have 2 columns, flight_number and company, the company column is a selector, 2 options to select: `QANTAS` and `AIR JAPAN`.

What I want to implement is, once flight_number is entered (foucs left), the compnay cell is updated. If flight number starts with `QF` then `QANTAS` is selected, if flight number starts with `JP`, `AIR JAPAN` is selected.

Below code works partially. After flight number is entered, if I click the company cell, the correct value is shown. But if I use tab to navigate to the company cell, the value is not correct.

I guess it's because clicking a cell and entering a cell by tab put the cell in different modes but I tried to add a `onCellFocused` on company cell and the row data is correct. So no idea why the display value is not correct.

```
export class Test3Component {
  columnDefs : ColDef[] = [
    {
      headerName: 'Flight Number',
      field: 'flight_number',
      editable: true,

    },
    {
      headerName: 'Company',
      field: 'company',
      editable: true,
      cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
      singleClickEdit: true,
      cellEditorParams: {
        values: ['QANTAS', 'AIR JAPAN']
      }
    },
  ];


  rowData = [
    { id: 1, flight_number: 'QF11', company: 'QANTAS' },
    { id: 2, flight_number: 'JP22', company: 'AIR JAPAN' },
  ];

  gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    getRowId: (data) => data.data.id // Use 'flight_number' as the unique identifier
  };

  addNewRow() {
    const newRow = { id: this.rowData.length + 1, flight_number: '', company: '' };
    this.rowData = [...this.rowData, newRow];
  }

  onCellValueChanged(event: any) {
    const newValue = event.data.flight_number as string;
    const updatedRow = { ...event.data };

    if (newValue.startsWith('QF')) {
      updatedRow.company = 'QANTAS';
    } else if (newValue.startsWith('JP')) {
      updatedRow.company = 'AIR JAPAN';
    }

    this.gridApi!.applyTransaction({ update: [updatedRow] });
  }

  onGridReady(params: any) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
  }

  private gridApi!: GridApi;

}
```